# Add a collection to another collection

Tags: collections, anylogic

I need to add to the collection "compagni_palestra" which is in the folder "palestra" the members of the collection "compagni" which is in the folder "classe" in order to keep the group "compagni" and put it into the extended group "compagni_palestra".
Here below the code that doesn't run.

```
//check in
palestra.compagni_palestra.addAll(classe.compagni) ;
```

The error showed by AnyLogic is the following:

> The method addAll(Collection<? extends Classe>) in the type `ArrayList<Classe>` is not applicable for the arguments (`ArrayList<Studente>`). Location: Mod_03/Studente/Palestra1 - State

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the error that each collection is for a different object type, one contains `Classe` type, the other contains `Studente` type.

If you want to store elements of any Java class, make sure the element class selected is `Object`.
[image]